# Something went wrong with the input pipeline in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to get a batch of 64 images each has [64,224,224,3] dimensions and labels have [64]. There are 8126 *_img_class* and *_img_names*. However, I am getting an unexpected output. Basically, I am getting nothing and script never terminate when I run it.

```
def _get_images(shuffle=True):

"""Gets the images and labels as a batch"""

     #get image and label list
     _img_names,_img_class = _get_list()
     filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(_img_names)

     #reader
     image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
     _, image_file = image_reader.read(filename_queue)

     #decode jpeg
     image_original = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file)
     label_original = tf.convert_to_tensor(_img_class,dtype=tf.int32)

     #image preprocessing
     image = tf.image.resize_images(image_original, [224,224])
     float_image = tf.cast(image,dtype=tf.float32)
     float_image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(image)

     #set the shape
     float_image.set_shape((224, 224, 3))
     label_original.set_shape([8126])

     #parameters for shuffle
     batch_size = 64
     num_preprocess_threads = 16
     num_examples_per_epoch = 8000
     min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue = 0.4
     min_queue_examples = int(num_examples_per_epoch *
                       min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue)
     if shuffle:
         images_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
                      [float_image,label_original],
                      batch_size=batch_size,
                      num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,
                      capacity=min_queue_examples + 3 *                               
                                               batch_size,
                      min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples)
    else:
         images_batch, label_batch = tf.train.batch(
                      [float_image,label_original],
                      batch_size=batch_size,
                      num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,
                      capacity=min_queue_examples + 3 * batch_size)

    return images_batch,label_batch

with tf.Session() as sess:

     tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

     # Coordinate the loading of image files.
     coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
     threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

     images,labels = _get_images(shuffle=True)

     # Get an image tensor and print its value.
     image_tensor,labels = sess.run([images,labels])

     # Finish off the filename queue coordinator.
     coord.request_stop()
     coord.join(threads)
```

When I set *enqueue_many=True* I am getting the following error.

```
TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the `queue_runners` after calling the `_get_images` function. As `queue` is defined in that function.

```
 ...
 images,labels = _get_images(shuffle=True)
 tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
 tf.local_variables_initializer().run()
 # Coordinate the loading of image files.
 coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
 threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
 image_tensor,labels = sess.run([images,labels])
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the output but my labels are in dimension (64,8126) and they are not getting shuffled. That is quite weird as I have already set its shape to [8126]. I would appreciate if you could throw some light on it. Thanks a

Comment: the problem is due to this line `label_original.set_shape([8126])`. Since label is a int here, you can set the shape  as `label_original.set_shape([1])` to make it 1D tensor. Or you mayn't set the shape.

Comment: I tried both the ways but both got failed. It gets mismatch dimension error. I kind of understand the error. For every Image, it considers 8126 elements as a label.

Comment: you can use `labels = tf.train.slice_input_producer([label_aslist])`